# Webpage content selector using WebEngine

Tags: java, javafx, css-selectors, jsoup, javafx-webengine

I want to load web content from a site *URI* and use selectors to get some useful information. I tried *JSoup* which allows me to [select elements with a CSS Selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-). Unfortunately *Jsoup* doesn't work as a browser and doesn't parse Javascript or handles cookies. That's why I looked into using the *JavaFX WebEngine* which works as a browser. But The *WebEngine* class returns [Documents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) which are very limited in selector possibilities compared to *JSoup*. The only selectors are by *Id* or by *Tag*.

Is there a clean way to use the WebEngine of JavaFX with more specialized selector possibilities?

Or are there other browser implementations in Java that allow for more specialized selections? The implementation should preferably be fast.

The best solution I can come up with for now is the following:

1. Use *WebEngine* of *JavaFX* to get a *Document* object of which the Javascript is parsed.
2. Convert the *Document* to a *String* using a *Transformer*.
3. Pass this String as argument to a *JSoup* object and use their *CSS* selector capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jsoup **does** support cookies. You just need to collect them and send them in every request along. So it is some work involved, but it is possible.

Your solution will work, but I doubt that the WebEngine of JavaFX is your best option, unless your application is employing JavaFX anyway and you need to display web content as well. In case you need it only for the task you described I would certainly recommend [selenium webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) for the job. With that you can remote control a real browser to access all content. There are bindings to many standard browsers, including phantomjs as a headless webkit solution for maximum compatibility and HTMLUnit for a Java only solution.

However, if speed is of great concern, I would give Jsoup another try. Try to find the AJAX calls the Javascript triggers and get the stuff you need directly. This would be much faster than selenium or WebEngine.

Comment: I don't want to open up a real browser, I have no need to render any GUI. I just want to simulate a browser with javascript and cookies and such. The Selenium HTMLUnitDriver comes close, but its javascript implementation is really lacking.

Comment: then go with phantomjs. It uses a headless webkit engine and should be able to run any real-world JavaScript. I found that the best solution in cases where I could not figure out the AJAX calls directly.

Comment: Ow I didn't realize there was a Java implementation as PhantomJSDriver as external library. The library is getting deprecated but it fits exactly the role I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
engine.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.